# Fragment dialog in particular row in android listview

Tags: android, listview, android-dialogfragment

[image]Here is what I have done till now.

```
  // Declaration
     NearByFriendsAdapter adapter;
     ListView lst_NearByFriends;

    // Initialization

    lst_NearByFriends= (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lst_NearbyFriends);


    list=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        NearByFriendsSupportClass nearByFriendsSupportClass=new NearByFriendsSupportClass();
        nearByFriendsSupportClass.setFriendsName("Chirag Solanki");
        list.add(nearByFriendsSupportClass);
    }

    adapter=new NearByFriendsAdapter(getActivity(),list,getFragmentManager());
    lst_NearByFriends.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my adapter with holder

```
 holder.img_Infoimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                InfoAlertDialog alertDialog=new InfoAlertDialog();
                alertDialog.show(fragmentManager, NearByFriendsFragment.class.getName());
            }
        });



private static class NearbyHolder{
   ImageView img_Infoimage;
}
```

I think this is enough to understand my problem.
Now when any user click on any row in listview, I want to open fragment dialog on that particular row. so please help me what to do to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Register an OnItemClickListener on your listview.

Comment: thanks for a quick reply, I am able to open dialog fragment but I do not know how to set the position of dialog on particular row of listview. In my code "InfoAlertDialog" is fragment dialog.

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "position of dialog on row of listview"?

Comment: I have added image. please check it. I want that fragment dialog besides row which is clicked.